# How to to get a list from a model based on function applied on a field without changing values in table

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django and developing a Webapp, I have a model named People with different fields like, first_name,last_name, Familyid.

Values in column Familyid looks like this:
example familyids:
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1.1

when i am creating view and get data in query set and displaying via template, i want to add one more column in query result set, with information FamilyID Dot Count i.e.  Family ID contains how many docts "." , values like Dot Count = 1 or 2 or 3 and so on. please help either should i do it in template(HTMl) or inside view and return it as queryset, and how. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `@property`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    family_id = models.CharField(...)

    @property
    def dot_count(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.family_id: 
            if i == '.': 
                count += 1
        return count
```

The, you can use `dot_count` like a property

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help, yes it has solved my requirement.